# VBA code to sum values in a range that is not constant

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am trying to make a macro where it will some all values from D2 till there is an empty cell and then move two steps down and continue this process in a loop. The code I made kept adding a constant number of cells and moving down but i want that range to be dynamic. can some one please help me with this.

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
Range("D2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-15]C:R[-1]C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-8]C:R[-1]C)"
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-8]C:R[-1]C)"
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0))
End Sub


80
8
10
40
8
16
30
16
30
26
34
26
46
10
70

24
5
36
24
24
48
6
6


12
10
6
18
36
48
54
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` is the cell that you are starting with, stored as a range, you want the following

```
WorksheetFunction.Sum(a, a.End(xlDown))
```

`End` is the code equivalent of `ctrl` and a direction arrow.  Because of this, I recommend doing some error checking around this to make sure that cells aren't empty.

**UPDATE**

My original answer assumed that you justed wanted the computed value in VBA.  Based on the added code, I would use the following:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim offset_rows As Long

    Set cell = Range("D2")

    Do While Not IsEmpty(cell.Offset(1, 0))
        offset_rows = Range(cell, cell.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        Set cell = cell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & offset_rows & "]C:R[-1]C)"
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note that I cleaned up the recorder code as `selection` is slow and has a tendency to lead to strange errors based on unexpected things being selected.

Comment: Sorry let me be more accurate. I am trying to make a macro where it will some all values from D2 till there is an empty cell and then move two steps down and continue this process in a loop. The code I made kept adding a constant number of cells and moving down but i want that range to be dynamic. I have edited my question to put my code as well. can you please look into it.

Comment: Hi Degustaf. Thank you for all the help. I tried the code you have given me but it is only calculating the first set. I have added a small sample of what my D column looks like. Now the code is adding values only till 70. Could you please try once more if you can write a code to add all the sets. Thank you.